# Merge multiple dataframes - memory issue

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have multiple dataframes (over 25) which consist of three columns "CompanyName", "Year" and "VariableX". The combination of the "CompanyNumber" and the "Year" is unique. I would like to merge all these dataframes to 1 big dataframe. With the column "CompanyNumber", "Year", "Variable from df1", "Variable from df2" etc. Each dataframe contains approximately 80000 rows.

```
data <-  Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), 
         list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10, 
         df11, df12, df13, df14, df15, df16, df17, df18, df19, df20, 
         df21, df22, df23, df24, df25))
```

I tried the above code, which works when I have less than 8 dataframes but does not work on the full data. I received the error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 126.7 Mb

I am currently working with 8GB, with R 64. I already cleared the memory of R with the `gc()` and `rm(list=ls())`.

Is there a way to merge these dataframes in R in a less memory taking way?

Comment: *which works when I have less than 8 dataframes* ... check the 8th dataframe for any inconsistencies

Comment: @Parfait or realize that if you don't specify `by` and all variable names are the same, you have a data frame with 640,000 rows instead of 80,000 after merging 8 dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically a problem you get when the combinations are not unique. That blows up your data frames exponentially. It might be a data error, but it might also be a consequence of `merge` not knowing which variables to use to merge. Starting from following list with data frames:

```
CompNr <- rep(sample(1:8000),10)
Year <- rep(sample(1:10), each = 8000)

dfs <- lapply(1:25,function(i){
  out <- data.frame(CompNr, Year, 
                    X = rnorm(80000, mean = 10*i))
  #make it a bit more difficult for merge by rearranging the rows
  out <- out[sample(nrow(out)),] 
})
```

This runs without problem on a computer with 6Gb:

```
out <- Reduce(function(x, y){
  merge(x, y, by = c("CompNr", "Year"),all=TRUE)
  }, dfs)
```

If I leave out the `by` argument, I run out of memory after the 3rd or 4th merge. That's because `merge` uses the intersect of the names in both data frames as `by` variables. In this case that's all variables of the data frame, including `X`. Hence with `all=TRUE` this becomes the equivalent of a simple `rbind`. This leads to a data frame with 320.000 rows after only 3 merging operations. You can easily see why you run out of memory.

This `Reduce` solution still gives a ton of warnings about duplicated names. You can solve this by renaming the variables before the merge, or by manually writing out the reduce operation yourself and taking care of the names in there. For example, using the `suffixes` argument:

```
memorymerge <- function(x, by = c("CompNr","Year"), ...){

  out <- x[[1]]
  nx <- length(x[-1])

  for(i in seq(nx) + 1){
    suff <- c("",paste0(".",i))
    out <- merge(out,
                 x[[i]],
                 by = by,
                 suffixes = suff,
                 ...
                 )
  }
  return(out)
}
```

This does the merge and gives the following result :

```
> out <- memorymerge(dfs, all = TRUE)
> str(out)
'data.frame':   80000 obs. of  27 variables:
 $ CompNr: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Year  : int  1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ X     : num  10.23 9.18 10.51 11.39 10.4 ...
 $ X.2   : num  21.3 19.2 19.4 18.9 20.8 ...
 $ X.3   : num  29.2 29.1 28.9 29.7 30.7 ...
 ...
```